# Find and Replace date in multiple files inside multiple folders

Tags: replace, automation, notepad++

I am looking to find and replace date across multiple files inside multiple folders. I tried recording using Notepad++ macro but cannot see any option to choose the date to be replaced while running the Macro. Is there any way to automate the task?

Example: I have .xml and .txt files

Sample 1- Replace date 2023-04-10 with 2023-05-24

Sample 2- Replace date 9782348**20230410**12 with 9782348**20230524**12

Sample 3- Replace :100:**230410** with :100:**230524**

Comment: Please [edit] your question, add some extracted lines from your text files with sample text. Explain what you expect in a  ***before*** and ***after*** way.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have all files in one directory or subfolders. Please think about a **backup copy** before testing!

Please keep in mind that replacing strings in large files may lead to unexpected results. It's hard to think of all the variants that occur. If you are sure you can try the following steps with Notepad++:

- Open one file in your workspace
- Open the dialog e.g. by <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Tick Search Mode `Normal`
- First only try for your needs *Find What:* `:100:230410`

Check the search result for correctness and then continue:

- Open Find in Files tab e.g. by <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Replace with: `:100:230524`
- Set Filter e.g. `*.txt`
- Set Directory
- First click the <kbd>Find All</kbd> button and check the results
- Click the <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd> button ***(at your own risk!)***

You can find some screenshots of the "Find in files" function in a similar question answered here:

[Using Regular Expressions to Delete a HTML Meta Tag Line of Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963007/using-regular-expressions-to-delete-a-html-meta-tag-line-of-code/73964451#73964451)